# Nokogiri Returning False on Empty String With .empty?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to remove empty `<p>` tags from a document using Nokogiri based gem, [ruby-readability](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-readability/). Using `.strip.empty?` in the console is working fine like this:

```
irb> p = Nokogiri::HTML("<p> </p>")
=> #<Nokogiri::HTML::Document...
irb> p.content
=> " "
irb> p.content.strip
=> ""
irb> p.content.strip.empty?
=> true
```

Running that same operation inside the [ruby-readability gem](https://github.com/cantino/ruby-readability/blob/master/lib/readability.rb#L414-L419), is returning `false`.

Inside that method I've added an extra call to test the `<p> </p>` line in my test HTML document:

```ruby
if @options[:remove_empty_nodes]
  node.css("p").each do |elem|
    puts "IS IT EMPTY?"
    puts element.content.strip.empty?
    elem.remove if elem.content.strip.empty?
  end
end
```

```
IS IT EMPTY?
false
```

Why is this returning `false`?

**Update:**

Per the descussion below I added a new element to the HTML document: `<p></p>`. If I call `element.content.bytes.inspect` or `element.content.strip.bytes.inspect` I get this:

```
ELEMENT:
<p> </p>
[194, 160]
ELEMENT:
<p></p>
[]
```

In IRB, `.strip` seems to be working:

```
irb> p.content.bytes.inspect
=> "[32]"
irb> p.content.strip.bytes.inspect
=> "[]"
```

Comment: Are you sure that `element.content` inside the `node.css` block is exactly one space and not something else?

Comment: I added it in the HTML document the same as I added it in IRB as described above. What kind of "something else" could it be? Do you mean something like `&nbsp;`? If I put `puts "'#{element.content.strip.empty?}'"` in the `node.css` block it returns `''`.

Comment: I'm thinking something like `"\u00a0"`. What does `element.content.bytes.inspect` look like?

Comment: In IRB it returns `"[32]"`. Inside the loop it returns `[194, 160]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`32` decimal is `0x20` in hex or `"\u0020"`, that's a single space in UTF-8 and `String#strip` knows what to do with it. The bytes `[194, 160]` are `"\u00a0"` which is a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space): it looks like a space but [`String#strip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-strip) won't recognize it as whitespace because:

> Whitespace is defined as any of the following characters: null, horizontal tab, line feed, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space.

You could use the [whitespace character property](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) instead of `#strip`:

```
elem.remove if elem.content.gsub(/\p{Space}/, '').empty?
```

Comment: That seems to have got it. Thanks for the detailed explanation and extra resources.

Comment: You're welcome. Unicode can be a massive PITA but a lot less painful than the alternatives.